# Jenkins suddenly showing "wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file" and times out with a FAILURE message

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, npm, groovy

I've been using Jenkins for years in a LEMP stack environment. Once I upgraded it to 2.164.3 with all the plugins installed, most of the non-heavy commands are running just fine, however, commands like **npm install and npm run build** are throwing the following error:

```
chunk {11} 11.e29c3bf0e5c6dc0d1345.js () 67 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} 12.feab1e5f3e9fe4c5151d.js () 67.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} 13.b50c5fcbf01d8b109ca8.js () 8.25 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14.7fd9fd5c4ed7b4abee56.js () 5.84 kB  [rendered]
wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXStagingDashboard@tmp/durable-d0e65b91
(JENKINS-48300: if on an extremely laggy filesystem, consider -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400)
[Pipeline] }
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
```

These are screenshots of the error logs I can see in Jenkins Log and **Durable** Plugin logs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the job logs showing the error while executing **npm run build prod**.

[image]

This is the **groovy** script triggering the job:

[image]

I tried to add the edit **HEARTBEAT** interval using the below but it only ended up waiting more time to get the same error at the end:
[image]

What do you guys advise?!

Comment: Anyone knows anything about this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Hello from the future. Any solution or suggestions for this?

Answer (score 4):

This could be due to lack of memory in your server. i had this problem due to low memory. Job was executed successfully after I run the job following a reboot

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

The problem was in my case, that the build task did not produce any output for a certain time. Therefore jenkins consider my task as dead and kills it.

**Solution**

Constantly produce some output, e.g. by setting the log level to debug.

**Remarks**

- This is not an elegant solution, because I don't want to have any debug output in my pipeline. But it's the only solution, that works for me.
- I've found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-issues/c/iS9ZiTSVRMM

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar to that. I ran a sonarqube analysis on a maven build job and it was successful initially. The error came up after installing stage view plugin. I had to uninstall the plugin for the sonarqube analysis to be successful again. I guess the error came up as a result of a low memory.